# Well I was suppose to make a Christmas tree but it worked and all but I'm trying to understand that basics of my 2nd for loop

Tags: java, for-loop

Well I made my Christmas tree but I am trying to find the logic behind why space>line doesn't stop when the numbers reach 5>5 because after that it will got to 4>6 and 3>7 making the loop false and stop going I believe.

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{

    for(int line=1; line<=10;line++) 
    {
        System.out.println();
        for (int space=10; space>line;space--)
        {
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
        for(int k=0;k<line;k++)
        {
            System.out.print("* ");
        }
            System.out.println();
    }
}
```

I got this which is correct but look at the spaces before each asterix not the line spaces.

```
         * 

        * * 

       * * * 

      * * * * 

     * * * * * 

    * * * * * * 

   * * * * * * * 

  * * * * * * * * 

 * * * * * * * * * 

* * * * * * * * * *
```

Comment: You have two `println`'s in your loop.

Answer (score 0):

"look at the spaces after each asterix not the line spaces", that's because you're printing:

```
System.out.print("* ");
```

The code you mentioned has nothing to do with spaces **after** asterixs but for **before**:

```
for (int space=10; space>line;space--)
```

For visual example replace that loop with:

```
for (int space=10; space>line;space--)
        {
            System.out.print("?");
        }
```

And you will get:

```
?????????*

????????* *

???????* * *

??????* * * *

?????* * * * *

????* * * * * *

???* * * * * * *

??* * * * * * * *

?* * * * * * * * *

* * * * * * * * * *
```

Comment: opps sorry I mean before but yeah I see that but I am trying to understand why when space>line  gets to be 5>5 or even 4>6 why doesn't it stop giving spaces since the arguments becomes false .

Comment: When 'line' is 5 then 'spaces' will go from (10,9,8,7,6) and when it's 6 the 'spaces' will go from (10,9,8,7). Can you elaborate more on what you don't understand?

Comment: @redsky where do you see that it doesn't stop?

Comment: guys thank you I understand now the 2nd loop restarts every-time line goes up